Spring data mongo: No converter found capable of converting from type String to object
I have the below document
@Document
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class User extends AuditEntity {

    @Id
    private String userId;

    private RelatedUser relatedUser;

    private Risk risk;

    private String victimId;

    private Status status;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Risk implements Serializable {
    private String code;
    private String label;
}

I have the below repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    @Query("{'victimId':?0, 'risk.code': 'ABC','status': {$nin:['CLOSED', 'CANCELLED', 'IN_PROGRESS']}}")
    List<User> findByVictimIdAndRiskABC(final String victimId);
}

When I executed the method findByVictimIdAndRiskABC, I encountered this error
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.user.models.Risk]

It seems you forgot @Document annotation on Risk class

Maybe are there some corrupted documents on table? try to search if there is a document with field "risk" saved as string instead of object.  Try this query: { risk: { $type: "string" } }
